# Django Bootstrap form is slow to render, how can I speed up?

Tags: django, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a large form (20 fields) that is taking forever to block render in Django + bootstrap-toolkit, as it can be seen in the following graphs:

[image: Time breakdown]

Also see [this block breakdown graph.](https://s3.amazonaws.com/changemyaddress.net/other/block-breakdown.gif)

What I've tried...

- Cache the view. The csrf token always makes it a new view thus it never actually caches.
- Split the form out into it's own block content then cache that block while keeping the csrf tags on the outside of the field.   Django had a hard time rendering that and the POST buttons wouldn't work.

I'm out of ideas and need some outside perspective on how to work around this.

Comment: install debug toolbar and see what's slowing it down.

Comment: @limelights It seems to be the html generation of each of the fields (and attrs).  The image was an overview but I have a step by step breakdown showing each field being render in python.  Just way to slow.

Comment: Do you render each field by itself?

Comment: @limelights
Form Class
   - Form Field Object
   - Form Field Object

Form Class pulled into template and rendered out.  It looks like each of the fields has it's own html block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it loading much faster by doing the following.

I pre-rendered out the form with the zillion block requests.
Opened browser requested the form.
Copied the form HTML code.
Created new html file with the pre-render HTML form.
Changed the 'VIEW''s GET request to use the new pre-rendered form HTML.
Added CRSF token just inside the form.

Response time was reduced from 5 seconds to .50 ms.

It's important to note you won't be able to use the cache decorated on that view.
You can use the <% cache %> template tags on the new HTML file with the form.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Form rendering is ridiculously slow.